# Do all gabumon have fur pelts?

Tags: digimon

I have only watched the first three versions of Digimon, and I don't remember seeing any gabumons other than the one who bonded with Matt.

So while reading about it in some [wiki](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Gabumon), I found this piece of information:

> Gabumon is a Reptile Digimon. Although it is covered by a fur pelt, it is still clearly a Reptile Digimon. (...)

So far, so good. I've seen the episode where it removes that pelt. But then there's this:

> (...) Due to its extremely timid and shy personality, it always gathers up the data which Garurumon leaves behind, and shapes it into a fur pelt to wear.

This seems to be more about an individual than a species as a whole.

So... do all other gabumons in general live without a garurumon pelt? Or do they have the habit of getting those bits of fur pelt data from the ones among them who have digivolved into garurumons?

Comment: However, it also says `When it is wearing the fur pelt, its personality does a complete 180° shift.`, which doesn't describe Matt's Gabumon.